# Sublime Text key mappings only for Vintage Mode

Tags: sublimetext

I know that the Vintage Mode for vim keymappings is entirely implemented using ST's Python and JSON convention.

The question is about how to cleanly organize the mappings in such a way as to have them not go into effect when vintage mode is disabled.

Do I:

1. "fork" the vintage mapping file and add to it, so that when the vintage mapping file is updated upstream (new version of ST, etc) I have to merge my changes back in manually
2. Insert the vintage-specific mappings in my user key map file so that I have to manually disable them if I were to switch off vintage?

I'm leaning towards the second, because I do not envision disabling vintage mode because vim keys are too ingrained in my head now, and I can simply leave it in insert mode to get 99% of the original ST behavior.

Comment: Are the key bindings you are trying to use active in command mode or insert mode?

Answer (score 0):

I think the question was misguided because the key mappings must already specify whether they take effect in insert or command mode. So if I turn off Vintage mode the command only bindings shouldn't come into effect anyway.

Plus it does not appear as though I will ever actually disable Vintage mode, so everything's sort of moot.